# Free SSL certificate providers

Tags: ssl

I'm looking to upload my CSR generated using my tools on my system and get free certificates.

I understand that this will come with constraints.

If you have used any such free service please let me know which would be a better choice.

Comment: (A) I suspect this Question is off-topic here, as it refers to services rather than a particular piece of software or library. Perhaps [SuperUser Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com). (B) Perhaps [Let’s Encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let's_Encrypt)?

Comment: As far as i know Let’s Encrypt does not allow our keys and CSR. Instead it generates its own for us. While we need to upload our CSR to get a free certificate.